# 28 dominoes lying in one direction what is the last one?

Tags: puzzle, pattern-matching

> Peter with a standard double six set lays 28 dominoes in one direction - what will be the last number on the end on then of the last domino?
>   Suppose he plays in both directions and discovers that he can use all the dominoes that he has available but Ann announces she hid one from before he started - which one will it be?

I have the answer 6 for the first part but anyone have a clue of the second part because in a pack there is 28 and if she hid one it makes it 29
this makes no sense to me
any one make sense of it?

Comment: The hidden one must be removed from the 28; you only have 27 dominoes left.

Comment: See my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2129527/domino-probability-problem/2129530#2129530

Comment: oh that makes more sense

Comment: @rhysand You're welcome! And welcome to math.SE! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to give numeric values.

In general, consider the half-dominoes; there are $8$ of each value. Since each  match point requires $2$ of the same value, a matched line of dominoes using the full set must inevitably have the same number at both ends, otherwise you would have an odd number of some half-domino value.

If a piece is removed and a matched line of the remaining dominoes is made, the answer depends on whether the removed piece was a "double" or not. If the removed piece is a "double", the ends of the matched line will be the same value as each other (but not necessarily the same value as the removed piece). If the removed piece was not a "double", the end values of the 27-piece matched line will match the two halves of the removed piece due to the parity argument used before.